# Identify and remap Fn key to Win key

Tags: keyboard, key, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, remap

Keyboard MSI Gaming Keyboard DS4100

This key has replaced left win key between alt and ctrl on the left and I need to remap it if clicked it toggles the right win key, but I cannot identify this key neither with ahk nor other programs like SharpKeys, none of them react when clicking this Fn key, ahk does not record any logs when pressed.

Tried this [Identify Special key keycode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897387/identify-special-key-keycode) but it does not record it in the log.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#InstallKeybdHook
#InstallMouseHook
NP:="Untitled - Notepad"

IfWinExist, % NP
WinActivate
else
IfWinNotExist, % NP
Run, Notepad.exe,, UseErrorLevel, nPID
nPID=%nPID%
if (ErrorLevel){
    MsgBox, there is a problem
}else{
    ToolTip, Notepad running as PID: %nPID%
    Sleep, 1000
    ToolTip
}
WinActivate, % NP
WinWaitActive, % NP
Send, {Raw}Hello %A_UserName%,`n`nRight click on the H icon on your traybar`ngoto -> "Open" ->          "View" - > "Key History and Script Info"`n`nThis area shows you your past keypresses. =]`n`n-islanq
return
```

Also tried SharpKeys, autodetect does not detect, tried setting manually where I found one key saying Wake (or Fn), but no effect.

Same with KeyTweak.

[image]
(zoom in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Function key called in AutoHotkey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435328/what-is-the-function-key-called-in-autohotkey)

Comment: There is no solution and it's 3 years old.

Comment: It doesn't matter how old it is, the answer doesn't change. It is still not possible, unless your keyboard manufacturer provides some magic driver software to remap the key.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find its virtual key and scan code (`vkXXscYYY`) by looking into key history?

[This post](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=29582) might help you out, depending on how the Fn key is implemented.